# time() function gives a less value then first time calling time()

Tags: php, time

Having this code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 SET posted='".mysql_real_escape_string(time())."'";
@mysql_query($query);
....
$q = "UPDATE table2 SET activated='".mysql_real_escape_string(time())."'";
@mysql_query($q);
```

Then, when I look in the database, the posted value in table2 is less than the posted value in table1.

How could this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How much is the difference? Seconds/Days?

Comment: `time()` won't produce injection, `mysql_real_escape_string` is non sense here.

Comment: A few seconds, the time of executing program on the dots... So it should be a few seconds more in table2, not less

Comment: Try to print SQLs and see what numbers are there. Possibly you have a different query after `update table2...` which is actually executed. Try to remove `@` from before mysql_query and see if you have some errors there

Comment: In real code, the statement is in an IF, so if there are error, they are logged. No errors so far. Waiting for some traffic to log SQL's

Answer (score 1):

this query is wrong

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 SET posted='".mysql_real_escape_string(time())."'";
@mysql_query($query);
```

it should be

```
$query = "update table1 SET posted='".mysql_real_escape_string(time())."'";
@mysql_query($query);
```

and try to store the time in variable and use it in query..

Comment: I think we can also put set on insert

Comment: In MYSQL `insert into ... set` syntax is allowed to insert new rows. That is just MySQL extention to SQL.